# How can I find the depth of a specific node inside a binary tree?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to figure out a recursive solution to this problem. The main thing is to return the level in the binary tree where the node is.

```
def find_depth(tree, node):
    if node == None:
        return 0 
    else: 
        return max(find_depth(tree.left))
        #recursive solution here
```

Using this class for the values:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right
```

Example: Calling `find_depth(tree, 7)` should return the level where 7 is in the tree. (level 2)

```
   3
  / \
  7  1  <------ return that 7 is at level 2
 / \  
 9 3
```

Comment: How would you search for a node in the tree? Use the same logic. If you have to go further down the node, return 1 + recursivefunction(), and if you find the node, return 0.

Comment: You're missing adding children to your tree. At the current state the class Tree only appends to the first level since you are not adding any levels to the children.

Comment: Hints: One more argument may be needed for depth recording. something special should be returned when the node is not found in a subtree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this is what you are looking for

```
    def find_depth(tree, node):
        if node is None or tree is None:
            return 0

        if tree == node:
            return 1

        left = find_depth(tree.left, node)
        if left != 0:
            return 1 + left
        right = find_depth(tree.right, node)
        if right != 0:
            return 1 + right

        return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide information about depth in `find_depth` call. It might look like this (assuming `0` is a sentinel informing that node is not found):

```py
def find_depth(tree, node, depth=1):
    if node == None:
        return 0

    if tree.value == node:
        return depth

    left_depth = find_depth(tree.left, node, depth+1)
    right_depth = find_depth(tree.right, node, depth+1)
    return max(left_depth, right_depth)
```

Then you call it with two parameters: `x = find_depth(tree, 7)`.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results -

1. base case: if the input `tree` is empty, we cannot search, return `None` result
2. inductive, the input `tree` is *not* empty. if `tree.data` matches the search `value`, return the current depth, `d`
3. inductive, the input `tree` is not empty and `tree.data` does *not* match. return the recursive result of `tree.left` or the recursive result of `find.right`

```py
def find (t = None, value = None, d = 1):
  if not t:
    return None              # 1
  elif t.value == value:
    return d                 # 2
  else:
    return find(t.left, value, d + 1) or find(t.right, value, d + 1) # 3

class tree:
  def __init__(self, value, left = None, right = None):
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

t = tree \
  ( 3
  , tree(7, tree(9), tree(3))
  , tree(1)
  )

print(find(t, 7)) # 2
print(find(t, 99)) # None
```

You can implement the `find` method in your `tree` class too

```py
def find (t = None, value = None, d = 1):
  # ...

class tree
  def __init__ #...

  def find(self, value)
    return find(self, value)

print(t.find(7)) # 2
print(t.find(99)) # None
```